Lit Web Component "object" properties are not visible in storybook "show code" code snippet
I have a requirement to develop web component library using Lit which will be used in multiple projects. In that library, one of the web component I required to develop is Chart web component. This web component is written over HighCharts and take configuration similar to HighCharts.
Let me share minimum required code snippet in order to understand problem:
chart.ts (Web Component)
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';
import Boost from 'highcharts/modules/boost';
import Data from 'highcharts/modules/data';
import Drilldown from 'highcharts/modules/drilldown';
import ExportData from 'highcharts/modules/export-data';
import { html, unsafeCSS } from 'lit';
import { property, state } from 'lit/decorators.js';
import tokens from '../../tokens/en/data/tokens-dark.json';
import { ENElement } from '../ENElement';
import styles from './chart.scss';

Drilldown(Highcharts);
HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
Boost(Highcharts);
Data(Highcharts);
ExportData(Highcharts);

/**
 * Component: en-chart
 * @slot - The components content
 */
export class ENChart extends ENElement {
  static el = 'en-chart';

  @property({ type: Object })
  chartOptions?: {} = {};

  static get styles() {
    return unsafeCSS(styles.toString());
  }

  private _renderChart() {
    const config = typeof this.chartOptions === 'string' ? JSON.parse(this.chartOptions) : this.chartOptions;
    // config processing
    return Highcharts.chart(this.shadowRoot.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.en-c-chart'), config);
  }

  /**
   * Updated lifecycle
   * 1. Iterates over the changed properties of the component after an update.
   * 2. Checks if the changed property is 'chartOptions' and it has been modified. In that case rerender chart
   * @param changedProperties - A map of changed properties in the component after an update.
   */
  updated(changedProperties: Map<string, unknown>) {
    /* 1 */
    changedProperties.forEach((oldValue, propName) => {
      /* 2 */
      if (propName === 'chartOptions' && this.chartOptions !== oldValue) {
        this._renderChart();
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    const componentClassNames = this.componentClassNames('en-c-chart', {
      'highcharts-dark-theme': true
    });
    return html`<div class="${componentClassNames}"></div>`;
  }
}

if ((globalThis as any).enAutoRegistry === true && customElements.get(ENChart.el) === undefined) {
  customElements.define(ENChart.el, ENChart);
}

declare global {
  interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
    'en-chart': ENChart;
  }
}

Now I want to demo this component on storybook. I am using storybook version 6. This is how I have configured storybook, in order to demonstrate it:
chart.stories.ts(Storybook)
import { html } from 'lit';
import { spread } from '../../directives/spread';
import './chart';

export default {
  title: 'Components/Chart',
  component: 'en-chart',
  parameters: { status: { type: 'beta' } },
  argTypes: {
    chartOptions: {
      control: 'object',
      description: 'Highchart chart options'
    }
  }
};

const lineChartOptions = {
  title: {
    text: 'U.S Solar Employment Growth',
    align: 'left'
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'By Job Category. Source: <a href="https://irecusa.org/programs/solar-jobs-census/" target="_blank">IREC</a>.',
    align: 'left'
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Number of Employees'
    },
    gridLineDashStyle: 'Dot'
  },
  xAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Year (2010-2020)'
    },
    accessibility: {
      rangeDescription: 'Range: 2010 to 2020'
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      label: {
        connectorAllowed: false
      },
      pointStart: 2010,
      marker: {
        enabled: false,
        lineColor: null,
        lineWidth: 2
      }
    }
  },
  chart: {
    marginTop: 100
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Installation & Developers',
      data: [43934, 48656, 65165, 81827, 112143, 142383, 171533, 165174, 155157, 161454, 154610]
    },
    {
      name: 'Manufacturing',
      data: [24916, 37941, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 36885, 33726, 34243, 31050]
    },
    {
      name: 'Sales & Distribution',
      data: [11744, 30000, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 30912, 29243, 29213, 25663]
    },
    {
      name: 'Operations & Maintenance',
      data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 11164, 11218, 10077]
    },
    {
      name: 'Other',
      data: [21908, 5548, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 17300, 13053, 11906, 10073]
    }
  ],
  responsive: {
    rules: [
      {
        condition: {
          maxWidth: 500
        },
        chartOptions: {
          legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

const BottomLegendLineChartTemplate = (args) =>
  html`<div style="height:500px;"><en-chart ${spread(args)} .chartOptions=${args.chartOptions} data-testid="chart"></en-chart></div>`;

export const BottomLegendLineChart = BottomLegendLineChartTemplate.bind({});
BottomLegendLineChart.args = {
  chartOptions: lineChartOptions
};

Now, I start storybook and I am able to see my component loaded and working correctly. But problem is that when I click "show code" in storybook, it is not showing chartOptions property passed in code snippet as shown in screenshot:

My .storybook/main.js is as follow:
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const NormalModuleReplacementPlugin = require('webpack').NormalModuleReplacementPlugin;

const themePath = (file = '') => {
  let node_modules = path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'node_modules');
  const cacheFile = `${node_modules}/.cache/storybook-theme/theme`;
  let theme = 'en';
  if (fs.existsSync(cacheFile)) {
    let cachedTheme = fs.readFileSync(cacheFile);
    cachedTheme = `${cachedTheme}`.replace(/\s+/, '');
    if (cachedTheme !== '') {
      theme = cachedTheme;
    }
  }

  return path.resolve(__dirname, `../tokens/${theme}/${file}`);
};

module.exports = {
  // Use webpack 5 so we have better control over entry/output and can push Theo/Yaml/CSS
  // to the right place
  core: {
    builder: 'webpack5'
  },

  // Tell Storybook where to find the stories
  stories: [
    './components/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx|mdx)',
    '../components/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx|mdx)',
    './recipes/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx|mdx)'
  ],

  staticDirs: ['./static'],

  // Include any addons you'd like to use in Storybook
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-a11y',
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@etchteam/storybook-addon-status',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
    'storybook-addon-themes',
    'storybook-addon-rtl',
    '@storybook/addon-docs',
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-coverage',
      options: {
        istanbul: {
          include: ['**/components/**'],
          exclude: ['**/ENElement.ts', '**/components/icon/**'],
          excludeNodeModules: true
        }
      }
    }
  ],

  // Customize our Webpack config
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // Loop over each of module rules in our config. Module rules define the loaders
    // that Webpack will use. We're, specifically, looking for the CSS rule
    config.module.rules.map((rule) => {
      // As we loop over the rules if the rule doesn't have a RegExp test or the
      // RegExp test doesn't match `.css` then we'll return the rule as-is with no
      // modifications being made.
      if (!rule.test || !rule.test.test || !rule.test.test('.css')) {
        return rule;
      }

      // If we're here then we're working with the CSS rule so we'll shift off the
      // first loader, which is the style-loader, since we want to manage styles
      // in lit-element, not via storybook/head injection
      rule.use.shift();

      // Return the modified CSS Webpack rule
      return rule;
    });

    // Add SCSS support
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss/,
      use: [
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            sassOptions: {
              importer: [
                function themeImport(url) {
                  const matches = url.match(/^THEME\/(.*)/);
                  if (!matches) {
                    return null;
                  }

                  const node_modules = path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'node_modules');
                  const cachedThemePath = path.resolve(node_modules, './.cache/storybook-theme/theme');
                  if (fs.existsSync(cachedThemePath)) {
                    this.webpackLoaderContext.addDependency(fs.realpathSync(cachedThemePath));
                  }

                  const overridePath = fs.realpathSync(themePath(matches[1]));
                  this.webpackLoaderContext.addDependency(overridePath);
                  if (fs.existsSync(overridePath)) {
                    return {
                      file: overridePath
                    };
                  } else {
                    return {
                      contents: ''
                    };
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    // Add custom SCSS support
    // config.module.rules.push({
    //   test: /\.scss/,
    //   use: [
    //     'css-loader',
    //     './loaders/sass-loader',
    //   ],
    // })

    // Add theo support
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.yml$/,
      use: ['css-loader']
    });

    // Add svg support
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      type: 'asset/source'
    });

    // Add theme support to JS imports
    config.plugins.push(
      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/(^|\!)THEME(.*)/, function (resource) {
        resource.request = resource.request.replace(/(^|\!)THEME/, '$1' + themePath());
      })
    );

    // config.cache = false;

    // Return the modified Webpack Config
    return config;
  },

  // Adjust the Babel config before it gets to Storybook
  babel: async (options) => {
    // Ensure the babel config is setup to work with Lit. Bug here describes the break, https://github.com/lit/lit/issues/1914
    // The GH Issue indicates that the decorator plugin should be configured with `decoratorsBeforeExport`, which
    // Storybook does not do. So, we'll add that in here.
    //
    // Unfortunately the `decoratorsBeforeExport` also conflicts with the Storybook default config of `legacy: true` so
    // we'll need to remove that too.
    // https://lit.dev/docs/components/decorators/#avoiding-issues-with-class-fields
    options.plugins = options.plugins.map((plugin) => {
      if (plugin[0].includes('@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators') || plugin[0].includes('@babel\\plugin-proposal-decorators')) {
        if (plugin[1].legacy) {
          delete plugin[1].legacy;
        }
        plugin[1].decoratorsBeforeExport = true;
      }

      return plugin;
    });

    return options;
  }
};

Please look into the issue and let me know how I can fix the issue.
